In bash, how to capture stdout and the exit code of a command when the -e flag is active?
To capture stdout and the exit code when the -e flag (exit the shell immediately when a command fails) is not set, I would use
OUTPUT="$(my_command)"
exit_code=$?

To capture the exit code with -e set, I would use
exit_code=0
my_command || exit_code=$?

But combining the two approaches doesn't work:
exit_code=0
OUTPUT="$(my_command || exit_code=$?)"

This doesn't set exit_code, because it is assigned in a subshell and the copy in the parent shell is not updated.
So, how do I capture stdout and the exit code? I could unset -e or e.g. write the exit code to a tempfile, but I would like something simpler.

you'd need exit_code=0; my_command || exit_code=$? to get the exit status in all cases.

@ilkkachu you're right. I had local exit_code=0 in an earlier version, but I wanted to remove the local and erroneously removed the whole line.

my_command || exit_code=$? also cancels the effect of the errexit option for the execution of my_command (and any code interpreted within including all called functions, recursively if my_command is itself a function), so do you mean that you want to cancel errexit for my_command and get its output and exit code?

Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 and then reconsider setting -e at all so you can keep your code simple, intuitive, and correct.

@StéphaneChazelas Yes, I want to handle failing of my_command manually. This is part of a larger script that has errexit set.

@EdMorton My code is part of a set of build scripts written in bash. I am now even more convinced that bash is not suitable for any serious programming, but at this point replacing the build scripts with something better is not worth the investment. And I already ran into several of the gotchas mentioned on that wiki page. But I think not setting errexit will not be a net improvement, especially when other non-bash-scripting-experts make changes and write the easiest code that looks like it works. Anyway, a large simple and correct bash script is a contradiction in terms, +e or -e.

I must have had a brainfart when I was trying to solve this problem. The solution is straightforward. Yet I wasn't able to find an answer with my search engine, so I decided to still add this question here.
Solution:
exit_code=0
OUTPUT="$(my_command)" || exit_code=$?

i.e, move the || exit_code=$? outside the subshell.
N.B: do not prefix this with export or local, doing so will overwrite the exit code of my_command. Setting variables as local or export can be done on in a separate command.

Related:  How is the return status of a variable assignment determined?

That boils down to how to disable the effect of errexit for one command, here a variable assignment.
errexit is cancelled when a command is involved in a condition like in

if cmd; then... (same with while/until; same in if cmd; other-cmd; then...)
! cmd
cmd || ...
cmd && ...

In, output=$(cmd) you have two commands:

a variable assignment simple command
inside the subshell whose output is captured to make up the value of that assignment, another simple command cmd:

With errexit on, if cmd fails, the subshell exits (with the same exit status), you'd find for instance that in var=$(false; echo here>&2), echo here is not run; the variable assignment exit status will be that of that subshell, so also a failure, so the shell process interpreting that assignment will also exit.
If that assignment is part of a condition, then errexit is disabled recursively in all the shell code that may be interpreted there.
In:
if
  ! output=$(cmd)
then
  echo>&2 It failed
fi

errexit is disabled for both the variable assignment and for cmd, and if cmd is itself a function for instance, for each command that that function runs even in subshells, even if that function explicitly calls set -o errexit / set -e itself.
Here if you want to handle the failure of cmd regardless of whether errexit is enabled or not, you can use that if ! output=$(cmd); then above or:
output=$(cmd) || {
  echo>&2 Handling failure
  exit 1
}

If you do need to get the actual value of the exit status in the handler, you can do:
if
  output=$(cmd)
  exit_status=$?
  [ "$exit_status" -ne 0 ]
then
  echo>&2 "It failed with status $exit_status"
  ...
fi

I you want to just record the exit status for now, maybe to handle it later, the canonical way to just cancel errexit for one command (with the caveat as noted above that it applies recursively) is to append && true.
cmd || true

Means that you want to completely ignore any failure of cmd. Not only errexit is cancelled, but the overall exit status will reflect success. While:
cmd && true

Cancels errexit but also preserves cmd's exit status in the exit status of the whole and-or list. So:
output=$(cmd) && true
exit_status=$?
other_commands
if [ "$exit_status" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo>&2 "Oh, BTW, cmd failed earlier with status $exit_status"
fi

If the code was output=$(cmd1; cmd2), you'll likely want to change it output=$(cmd1 && cmd2) because, with errexit cancelled, cmd2 would otherwise be run even if cmd1 failed.
Or you could give up on errexit altogether as many people do and recommend doing, and do proper error handling throughout your script. It's a good exercise to stop and think of what should happen would a command fail and decide what to do in that case, rather than hoping errexit will do the right thing which in practice it rarely does consistently except in the simplest of scripts.

Funny how you and EdMorton both argue for giving up on errexit by pointing to a wiki page where the conclusion is not unanimously to abandon errexit, but where one author concludes that enabling -e is still better than disabling it. In my case (build scripts running in a gitlab pipeline), I could go the route of checking all commands explicitly, but I probably would skip that for commands I "know" will never fail, and when others make changes they probably won't check every command properly. So having the script exit on most failures is still better than not setting errexit at all.

One possible way is to use command like this:
OUTPUT="$(my_command)" ; exit_code=$?

With this you avoid one line and directly assign the exit code
In case of -e set you can disable it temporary, exec the command and then set it again. Here you can find some example script to do this.

With errexit enabled, that exit_code=$? won't be reached if $? is anything but 0. You'd need OUTPUT=$(my_command) && true; exit_code=$?. Like with || ... that && cancels the errexit for the execution of my_command (and any code interpreted within including all called functions, recursively if my_command is itself a function)

@StéphaneChazelas, in my environment (GNU bash, version 4.4.12(0)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)) this work fine. Checked with ls /existing_dir and ls /nonexistingdir

Did you try with the errexit option enabled (as with set -e)? bash -o errexit -xc 'output="$(ls /x)"; exitcode=$?'

@StéphaneChazelas, yes, it do not pass the exit code. But in the environments I work with this option is not set. And IMHO this option will be applicable in rare cases.

@RomeoNinov rare or not the question is specifically asking "In bash, how to capture stdout and the exit code of a command when the -e flag is active?" (emphasis mine). Otherwise capturing the exit status is as simple as you show in your answer.

@EdMorton, edit my answer, to add comment and link to script to unset and set it back :)

OK, but I doubt if the OP will want to unset it even temporarily if they're relying on it. Anyway, not my downvote...

@EdMorton, this is kind of speculation :) I, personally, can't get a reason why OP will not like to disable it temporary.

I already mentioned in the question that unsetting and re-setting -e was a possibility, but I was looking for something simpler.
